# C program to print directory names in a directory and exclude current directory and parent directory

Tags: c, linux, directory, dirent.h

I have a program that prints out all the directories listed inside a specific directory, by checking that `d_type == DT_DIR`

the program works, but also prints out the parent directory `..` and the curent directory `.`

I tried to set an if statement to check that `d_name != ".." or "."`, but it still printed parent and current directory

here is my code with the added if statement to

```
 directory = opendir("/home/user/adirectory");

    if(directory != NULL)
    {
        while(entry = readdir(directory)) {
            if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR && entry->d_name != ".." && entry->d_name != ".")
                printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }


    }
```

unfortunately this is the output, where **dir2** is a directory inside **adirectory**

```
..
dir2
.
```

I would like instead an output that only shows this directory without dot or two dots

```
dir2
```

Comment: Instead of strcmp() use strncmp() to make code safer.

Comment: Another approach to list the directories is by using: `int listDir(const char *dirpath) {
    glob_t gdir = { 0, };
    regex_t r1 = { 0, };
    regex_t r2 = { 0, };
    const char p1[] = "\(^\[\.\]\{1,2\}\/\)";  // RE for filtering
    const char p2[] = "\(\/$\)";               // RE for inclusion
    char pwd[PATH_MAX + 1] = { 0, };

    getcwd(…);
    chdir(…);

    result = regncomp(&1, p1, strlen(p1), REG_EXTENDED);
    result = regncomp(&2, p2, strlen(p2), REG_EXTENDED);

// STUFF code posted in another comment below
    regfree(&r1);
    regfree(&r2);

    chdir(…);

    return 0;
}`

Comment: Code to be stuffed inside the above comment:  `if ((glob(".*", (…|GLOB_MARK), NULL, &gdir) == 0) &&
        (glob("*",  (…|GLOB_MARK | GLOB_APPEND), NULL, &gdir) == 0)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gdir.gl_pathc; i ++) {
      char *ps = gdir.gl_pathv[i];
            int sz = strlen(gdir.gl_pathv[i];
            if ((REG_NOMATCH == regnexec(&reg1, ps, sz), 0, NULL, 0)) &&
                (REG_NOMATCH != regnexec(&reg2, ps, sz), 0, NULL, 0)))
                printf(" [%02d] %s\n", (i + 1), ps);
        }
        globfree(&gdir);
    }`

Comment: Please note that I have some edits in the above comments/code such as "...", so you may need to change them accordingly to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparison in C can be done using the **strcmp** function. You can't compare strings using the = sign. Below is your code updated with strcmp.

```
directory = opendir("/home/user/adirectory");

    if(directory != NULL)
    {
        while(entry = readdir(directory)) {
            if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(entry->d_name,"..")!=0 && strcmp(entry->d_name, ".")!=0)
                printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [strcmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c).

Comment: so it would be something like `strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") != 0` ?

Comment: yes to my question cause it worked

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is that you are using `!=` operator on strings which is *NOT* valid in C. You have to use `strcmp` function to compare two strings. If you don't know how to use `strcmp` function then you can google about it. Here lies the problem,

```
    if(entry->d_type == DT_DIR && entry->d_name != ".." && entry->d_name != ".")
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c?lq=1) may be helpful.